# Why clause IN not working in my code?

Tags: php, mysql

Why clause IN not working in my code ?

```
<?PHP
$id_user = array('aaa' , 'bbb');
$ids = join(',',$id_user);  
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username IN ($ids) order by id asc";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$tcount = mysql_num_rows($result);
$i = 0;
$number = 0;
while($i<$tcount) 
    {
     $number++;
     mysql_data_seek($result,$i);
     $datas=mysql_fetch_array($result);
        {
          $id = stripslashes(str_replace('\r\n', '<br>',($datas['id'])));
          echo $id;
          echo "<br>";
        }
    $i++;
    $count++;
     }
?>
```

Comment: You're not escaping your usernames. `IN (aaa, bbb)` is invalid SQL, use http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php and the like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
$ids = join("','",$id_user);  
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username IN ('$ids') order by id asc";
```

Comment: Hello, SQL injection possibility

Answer (score 0):

your usernames are strings and thus should be enclosed in quotes

```
$id_user = array('aaa' , 'bbb');
$ids = join(',', array_map(function($v) {
    return sprintf('"%s"', mysql_real_escape_string($v)); 
}, $id_user));  
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username IN ($ids) order by id asc";

// here goes the rest of your code
```